# How can I create an Anaconda env from the env folder?

Tags: anaconda

How can I recreate this environment in Anaconda from this folder? I don't have a yaml. The folder is on an external drive. I had to do an unexpected fresh install of Windows, but luckily had the anaconda3 folder backed up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to try generating a YAML from the environment:

```bash
conda env export -p /path/to/env/gdal > gdal_env.yaml
```

Then recreate from the YAML:

```bash
conda env create -n gdal -f gdal_env.yaml
```